# Compiler doesn't find reference to zip_get_num_entries on Windows

Tags: c++, dll, zip, cmake

I want to use libzip in my program in C++ to extract files from a zip archive. So firstly, I get the number of files in it, get their names and read them. To get the number of files, I use 'zip_get_num_entries'. Its prototype is:

```
zip_uint64_t zip_get_num_entries(struct zip *, int)
```

And the way I use this function:

```
int nbrEntries(0);
zip *archive = zip_open("myZip.zip", 0, 0);
nbrEntries = zip_get_num_entries(archive, 0);
```

When I wrote this code, Code::Blocks suggested me zip_get_num_entries, so there's no problem of header. But when I compiled, the compiler (MinGW) told me that:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__zip_get_num_entries'
```

So I tried its deprecated equivalent, zip_get_num_files and it worked. I included to the project libzip.dll.a that I made with CMake. I had two files: libzip.dll and libzip.dll.a.

I'm sure it's a library problem (notice that I didn't have this problem on MacOS) but I don't know how to solve this. Thank you!

EDIT: I searched their website and read that the implementation of zip_get_num_files was new when they released the library available on the website. So I searched in their Mercurial repo and found versions that were released 2 days ago (a little bit newer than the release on the website, which has almost 1 year). I built it with CMake and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined reference" means that there is no definition/implementation (as opposed to declaration/prototype) of the function available. You forgot to *link* the library. Since you use MinGW with `g++`, it will take something like `-lzip` on the command line or as parts of `LDFLAGS`.

There is a chance that you misconfigured something, too - in which case the symbol name may be different depending on a define. But the most likely case is that you forgot to link the dependency.

Comment: I added -lzip in the menu "Compiler settings" > "Other options" in my project build options, but there is always the same message :-/ What thing could I had misconfigured?

Comment: Oh I succeed to compile my program!! I downloaded from their Mercurial repo a newer version and it worked! http://hg.nih.at/libzip/rev/3bf116d0b3e9

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed to use zip_get_num_entries! I searched their website and read that the implementation of zip_get_num_files was new when they released the library available on the website. So I searched in their Mercurial repo and found versions that were released 2 days ago (a little bit newer than the release on the website, which has almost 1 year). I built it with CMake and it worked!